# How do I store video from VLC to a file?

Tags: delphi, video-streaming, vlc

I use Delphi and I need to capture video from IP camera and store it to a file. I use TVLCPlugin (ActiveX component from VLC).

```
p: TVLCPlugin;
***
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Options: OleVariant;
begin
  Options := ':sout=#duplicate{dst=display,dst=std{access=file,mux=asf,dst=D:\job\Camera\zzz.mpg}}';
  p.addTarget(
    'http://...', //MRI
    Options,
    VLCPlayListInsert, 0);
  p.play;
end;
```

So I can see video on the form, but it doesn't store it to the file. Can anyone help me to set the options correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not asking on VLC forum about VLC options?

Comment: I've found several similar questions on these forum without answers, it seems like nobody knows. Also I've asked another question there but nobody has answered. So I decided stackoverflow might be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much for asking this question, it inspired me to start writing a surveillance system wrapping our RTSP cameras in Delphi (which I've already make a simple version in a web page using the same component)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at TVideoGrabber

http://www.datastead.com/products/tvideograbber/overview.html

Comment: Well, I'll try if I don't find out how to do it using VLC.. Thank you!

Comment: Videograbber sucks, I own it and reverted back to using DSPack due to its (lack of) speed and bugs. I would recommend DSPack though! That way you get to do exactly what you need, without the bloatness of Videograbber. OK, I'm being a bit harsh there, and while it does do a LOT of things, IMO it does TOO much.

Comment: Hmm.. This is interesting, I'll try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to display the video feed? If you don't, you could just download the HTTP feed using one of the ways to do a HTTP request in Delphi, e.g. with Indy's TIdHTTP.

Comment: Yes, displaying video during recording is required. Besides, I've tried, but when I open received data using VLC player video is played with wrong speed. It's quicker than the real time. I hoped if I use VLC, video will be stored correctly. Besides the implementation looks much easier with VLC.